# "Bid" is to "counterbid" as "quote" is to what?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, analogy

Bids and counterbids are relevant in auction scenarios. But generally, when a seller/service provider sends a quote to a customer, the customer tends to negotiate. What is the price that the customer quotes back?

Comment: Counter-offer seems appropriate here.

Comment: Please make an effort to find an answer and let us know what you found.

Comment: @Kris sure .... I'm already unto it.

Comment: @Kris, Just contacted my friend who is a graduate in English language. He says that counterbid and counter offer can be used synonymously.

Answer (score 1):

Investopidia defines [counterbid](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/c/counterbid.asp) as:

> - A purchase offer made in counter to the offer of another potential purchaser. The term is often used in discussing the sale of one business to another. During a bargaining process it is not uncommmon for each side to issue multiple counter offers during the negotiation process.

***Counter offer/purchase offer*** is the expression you are looking for:

> - ***Counter offers can come in a variety of options. During a sale negotiation either party will make counter offers opposing the other party's offer to reach an agreed price which more closely suits their preferred price***. Informal counter offers occur on a daily basis as well, when deciding where to eat lunch to what to watch on the television.